# How to get all messages with me and marge, when receiver_id is my_id OR sender_id is my_id

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to receive all my messages where sender_id is my_id or receiver_id is my id. I receive them but cannot recover them assembled.
An example is shown in the picture, how to put all the messages together?

Maybe i can get this data with LARAVEL?

**WITHOUT GROUP BY**

```
SELECT sender_id,receiver_id,message FROM messages WHERE sender_id= 1 OR receiver_id= 1
```

[image]

**WITH GROUP BY**

```
SELECT sender_id,receiver_id,message FROM messages WHERE sender_id= 1 OR receiver_id= 1 GROUP BY sender_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your Model name is Message then you can do it like this:

```
Message::where('sender_id', 1)->orWhere('receiver_id', 1)->get();
```

Comment: i can get a data,but i cant marge fields when im not a sender,im a receiver,and he send me two datas 1-2 and 2-1 i want to marge it